# How can I make pressing Super+[number] multiple times cycle through open windows of an application?

Tags: shortcut-keys, desktop-environments, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

On Ubuntu 18.10, when I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> for an application with a single window, that window is brought to focus. If there are multiple windows though, I get a popup selection which requires me to choose which window I want, and then press Enter.

[image]

Is there a way I can get the following behavior?

- Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> and releasing focuses the first window of the application at <kbd>[number]</kbd> on the dock.
- Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> and holding Super displays the popup.

  - Then pressing <kbd>[number]</kbd> multiple times cycles through the available windows.
  - Releasing both keys on the selected window focuses that window.

This is the behavior on Windows, and I'm almost positive it's the behavior I had with Gnome on a different distribution. I might have had an extension installed or something though.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/) gets very close to the above behavior. The only thing it doesn't do is show the window previews as a popup when holding down <kbd>Super</kbd> after pressing a number. I would love to know if there's a solution for that.